# Merging new theme and plugins from development site to production

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, staging, production

I have a development site which uses a different theme to the live site as well as a few extra plugins. I would like to make the dev site live whilst keeping all of the posts and previous plugins belonging to the live site.
I do also have additional taxonomies, categories and custom posts types in the dev site. Not sure if this complicates matters.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the Live website, Go to WordPress Dashboard and select Tools / Export
Check Posts, Pages and Media.

WordPress will export an XML with the data.

On the Production website, Go to WordPress Dashboard and select Tools / Import / WordPress. Run the installer and import XML data form Live website.